# Google servers see website differently

Tags: search, google-search, pagespeed, google-search-console

I Googled one of our sites today (gamestyling.com) and saw that the results where in Chinese. It looks like our site was hacked but I see no traces of that. When opening the site all looks normaal (no Chinese).

On further inspection it seems that Google doesn't see the website correctly:

1. I cannot verify in Google search console. When I use the meta tag it shows me it detected a completely different tag.
2. When running pagespeed insight the preview does show Chinese: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=gamestyling.com

Also, when running the site through a proxy it looks completely normal.

Any idea how I can get Google to see my site correctly or what is causing this issue?

UPDATE

I now have access to Google search console and found that someone already had access to the property (2nd user):

[image]

I cannot remove the user because it uses a meta tag that google thinks is still in the header but doesn't appear in my code. So I'm still not sure if someone is playing tricks on Google or that we've been actually hacked. Note; nothing has changed on the server itself.

UPDATE2

This article describes exactly what's going on; https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/09/malicious-google-search-console-verifications.html. I must say that's an amazing safety fault on Google's part...

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced this issue on one of the site and resubmitted website for review in google webmasters. Search results in google were corrected in couple of days.

Comment: Did you also have the issue with search console at the time? That you weren't able to verify or that your site wasn't verified anymore?
My whole problem right now is that I can't resubmit because Search console isn't working :)

Comment: To be fair, I could submit in Google Webmaster. 

Have you tried verifying by alternative methods eg uploading file, or analytics code etc?

Comment: I finally was able to access Google search console/webmaster tools. I did a fetch as google but still saw the Chinese version of the website which I saw before. It's still a very strange issue, but at least I now have access to search console.

Comment: Just recheck wordpress plugins etc as sometimes these may be reason. Otherwise Chinese characters should go away in next couple of days. 

Just curious how did you manage to access console finally?

Comment: I don't think it will go away by itself. I found this article which describes exactly what's going on. https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/09/malicious-google-search-console-verifications.html Pretty interesting way of hacking, and a major flaw of google search console. In the end DNS verification worked for me.